# Laravel Error returns when it does json_decode

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel

I get the data in json format with the help of javascript. The javascript code I wrote actually sends the data in the format I want as follows:

```
var log_lists = JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, $scope.log_list));
```

when I checked it on the internet, I checked that the incoming data is in json format and it was verified by all

When I send the requests, it is received correctly by the controller and when I return, I see the data returned in the console as follows.

My controller code

```
$log_example = $request->all();
return $log_example;
```

**return data**

```
{
   "0":["1","SALES","5,00","REMOVED"],
   "1":["2","SALES","10,00","REMOVED"],
   "2":["1","BUYER","2","DROPPED"]
}
```

I use the json_decode function to run it in the foreach loop and when I return the data again I get the error "server error"

```
return json_decode($log_example, true);
```

// returns with errors

I couldn't find where I made a mistake.

Thank you for your help and suggestions.

Comment: The json seems to be fine. Try `var_dump($log_example)` or `Log::info($log_example);` as well as `Log::info(json_last_error_msg());` after you attempt to decode it. You'll have to separate out the decode from the return, however.

Comment: `$request->all()` returrn an array by default
just return it without `json_decode`

Comment: thanks @MohamedMelouk true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$request->all() return an array by default.
First encode and then decode as below

```
$log_example = $request->all();
$logs = json_encode($log_example);
$data = json_decode((string) $logs, true);
return $data;
```